# I want to Maintain User Presence in Firestore or Firebase of one device from multiple devices who accesses the single user credentials

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to maintain user presence in Firestore or Firebase. Actually the single user account handled by multiple mobiles devices and one tablet and that tablet maintain or do actions or provide functionality against my firestore data change. so i need to maintain presence of tablet in Firestore or Firebase so other mobile device understand the tablet working or not.

So please give me some solution on that.

I use Firebase node to check connection status. code below but i not give the proper response e.g when i remove the lan cable from router then also `onDataChange` not fire.for disconnection.

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference myConnectionsRef = database.getReference(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/tab/connections");

        // stores the timestamp of my last disconnect (the last time I was seen online)
        final DatabaseReference lastOnlineRef = database.getReference(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/tab/lastOnline");

        final DatabaseReference connectedRef = database.getReference(".info/connected");
        connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                if (connected) {
                    DatabaseReference con = myConnectionsRef.push();

                    // when this device disconnects, remove it
                    con.onDisconnect().removeValue();

                    // when I disconnect, update the last time I was seen online
                    lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                    long timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

                    // add this device to my connections list
                    // this value could contain info about the device or a timestamp too
                    con.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);

                }else {

                    long timestamp2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                System.err.println("Listener was cancelled at .info/connected");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are using the Firebase Realtime database or the new Cloud Firestore, what you are doing in your code is called a `1:1` relation between a user and a connection. You are looking for a user that may be connected from multiple devices. If you are using a flag that can hold a value of true or false depending on the connection status, you'll have a problem, which is if the user will disconnect from one of those devices, the `onDisconnect()` method from that particular device is called and will set `online` to `false` while the users may still be connected on another devices.

In my opinion, you should not rely on having a 1:1 relation between a user and their connection(s). The [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample) in the official documentation treat connections as a collection and assume that the user is connected as long as there is any "connect Id" (generated by `push()`) method left for that user. I recommend you do the same thing, to prevent hard to debug race conditions and connection problems

Comment: Actully i update the onDisconnected timetsamp from single device not from all . on our case there is multiple devices from them one is tablet and all other are mobile devices.and code for mobile app and tablet app is different .so i want maintain tablet connection status not mobile devicess. all mobile and tablet access the same user data.      
 so i write above code for tablet app

Comment: This is the exact same thing that I already said. You are updating from a single device, not from all and this is the problem. If you want to keep the tablet connection status, then you need to be connected. If you are disconnected, all other devices will remain connected. The solution is as in the example above. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You can update connected flag with device id on firebase realtime database, After login .

So all other devices will know about other devices.

While logout / on application Close, Make that flag to false.

Comment: but i have one issue is that how firebase maintain info/isConnected? it depends on single device or multiple devices? i read that it maintain connection response on device presense on firebase server. but i do not understand what exactly happen.

Comment: You can create a bean with deviceID and boolean flag isConnected, and store it on firebase database, You have to create this feature irrespective to firebase